# Type in input programmatically via dispatch event in JS

Tags: javascript, html, input, dom-events, keyboard-events

How can type in input like typing by keyboard? I know we can do it by set Input value, but how I can really simulate keyboard inputting?

Here is sample code that show keydown but type nothing in input.

html code:

```
<p>Info: <input id="info" style="width:50%"></p>
<p>show: <input id="show" style="width:50%"></p>
<p><button onclick="showType()">Type in show</button></p
```

js code:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
  document.getElementById("info").value = 
    "key= "+ev.key+" : "+ev.code+" : "+ev.keyCode;
}, true);

function showType(){
  document.getElementById("show").focus()
  document.getElementById("show").dispatchEvent(
  new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
    key: "d",
    code: "KeyD",
    keyCode: 68,
    shiftKey: false,
    ctrlKey: false,
    metaKey: false
  })
);
}
```

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/eYJwqLe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Auto-repeat_handling_prior_to_Gecko_5.0) it's not allowed due to security reasons. So, you need to update the value manually.

> Note: Manually firing an event does not generate the default action associated with that event. For example, manually firing a key event does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input. In the case of UI events, this is important for security reasons, as it prevents scripts from simulating user actions that interact with the browser itself.